# Wordpress - Apache FollowSymlinks for themes, using Mac lion

Tags: mysql, apache, wordpress, symlink

I've installed wordpress locally on my Mac (lion)
After enabling vhosts, I've created an entry in my hosts file to point "wordpress" to 127.0.0.1

My vhosts.conf contains:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/alex/Sites/wordpress"
    ServerName wordpress
    <Directory />
            Options FollowSymLinks  
            AllowOverride None
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

This works, and I can access the default wordpress install, no problem.

Basically, inside my wp-content/themes folder, I've put a symlink to (for example)
/Users/Alex/Projects/SomeTheme/

This folder contains my theme files

However, it's just not detecting the theme (doesn't show up in WP admin)
If I copy the folder to wp-content/themes, then it works. Symlinks aren't being followed

In my /etc/apache2/users/alex.conf I have:

```
<Directory "/Users/alex/Sites/">
    Options Indexes MultiViews FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I'm obviously missing something somewhere....

Comment: I think people over at servervault might be able to help..

Comment: yeah.. i think i posted this on the wrong site.. can it be moved?

Answer (score 4):

Wordpress has issues using symlinks. This is due to how PHP handles the `__FILE__` magic constant. In PHP, `__FILE__` returns the absolute path for the file it is run within. Unfortunately it ignores symlinks in that process. (ie. while you might be accessing the file through `/opt/wordpress/instance/wp-content/sym-themes/pretty` and the file is actually in `/opt/content/themes/pretty`, when `__FILE__` is called, instead of returning `/opt/wordpress/instance/wp-content/sym-themes/pretty` which is what wordpress expects, it returns `/opt/content/themes/pretty`.

Wordpress uses heavy use of `__FILE__` in it's code and also the `basename()` function to compare the wordpress root directory against the theme directory to get the name of the theme directory for things like parsing files. Due to how PHP handles the `__FILE__` magic constant, Wordpress tries to match the paths but since they are two different ones, it just appends one path to the other and you end up with a path to something that doesn't exist.

Unless you plan on doing a LOT of code moficiations, I highly recommend not using Symlinks anywhere in the wordpress structure.

Answer (score 1):

As @Drahkar has pointed out, symlinks are difficult in WordPress. To change the theme directory, use a simple plugin:

```php
add_filter( 'theme_root', 'sp8963532_theme_root' );
function sp8963532_theme_root()
{
    return 'FULL_LOCAL_PATH_TO_YOUR_THEMES_DIRECTORY';
}

add_filter( 'theme_root_uri', 'sp8963532_theme_root_uri' );
function sp8963532_theme_root_uri()
{
    return 'URI_TO_YOUR_THEMES_DIRECTORY';
}
```

Copy the code into a file, and put the file in `wp-content/mu-plugins/`.

Comment: This won't resolve issues with things like Caching. Honestly its better to just not use symlinks with Wordpress.

Comment: This solution is an _alternative_ for symlinks. Caching is not a problem here. See [this answer for](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/15483/symbolic-links-on-dev-box-with-plugins-and-stylesheets/15484#15484) a simliar case.